# How to initiate a thread in a class in C++ 14?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

```
class ThreadOne {
public:
    ThreadOne();
    void RealThread();
    void EnqueueJob(s_info job);

    std::queue<s_info> q_jobs;

private:
    H5::H5File* targetFile = new H5::H5File("file.h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC);
    std::condition_variable cv_condition;
    std::mutex m_job_q_;
};

ThreadOne::ThreadOne() {
}

void ThreadOne::RealThread() {
    while (true) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_job_q_);
        cv_condition.wait(lock, [this]() { return !this->q_jobs.empty(); });

        s_info info = std::move(q_jobs.front());
        q_jobs.pop();
        lock.unlock();      
        //* DO THE JOB *//  
    }
}

void ThreadOne::EnqueueJob(s_info job) {
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_job_q_);
        q_jobs.push(std::move(job));
    }
    cv_condition.notify_one();
}

ThreadOne *tWrite = new ThreadOne();
```

I want to make a thread and send it a pointer of an array and its name as a struct(s_info), and then make the thread write it into a file. I think that it's better than creating a thread whenever writing is needed.

I could make a thread pool and allocate jobs to it, but it's not allowed to write the same file concurrently in my situation, I think that just making a thread will be enough and the program will still do CPU-bound jobs when writing job is in process.

To sum up, this class (hopefully) gets array pointers and their dataset names, puts them in `q_jobs` and `RealThread` writes the arrays into a file.

I referred to a C++ thread pool program and the program initiates threads like this:

```
std::vector<std::thread> vec_worker_threads;
vector_worker_threads.reserve(num_threads_);
vector_worker_threads.emplace_back([this]() { this->RealThread(); });
```

I'm new to C++ and I understand what the code above does, but I don't know how to initiate `RealThread` in my class without a vector. How can I make an instance of the class that has a thread(RealThread) that's already ready inside it?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite grasp the nature of the difficulty. If you need a single thread, then just have a variable of type `std::thread`. That variable could be a member of some class, if needed; e.g. could even be a member of `ThreadOne`.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Thank you for the comment. Could you give an example please? I remember reading that you can't just make a thread inside an instance of a class like you do with a function in main().

Comment: @maynull "_I remember reading that you can't just make a thread inside an instance of a class like you do with a function in main()_" Why? Where did you "remember" this from?

Comment: `class ThreadOne {std::thread thread_; void StartThread() { thread_ = std::thread([this]{ RealThread(); }); } };` Something along these lines.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik But, one shouldn't forget to `join` the thread, in the destructor.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Thank you so much! It works like a charm!

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius I remember reading that you have to use lambda expressions and something dynamic? to make a thread using a method. I'm sorry if it's not correct!

Comment: @maynull Neither of those things are required (though Igor used a lambda expression in his example which works just as well), see my answer. Also, please don't add "Solved" or anything similar to your question. Once you have accepted an answer, it will be shown with a green indicator, and if you don't accept an answer, then this will be reflected as well.

Comment: @maynull So, you had problems using `std::thread` as a class member, or using non-static methods, as a thread function? Those mean different things. Every bit of those can be done, so am not sure what you meant by "can't use".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can gather, and as already discussed in the comments, you simply want a `std::thread` member for `ThreadOne`:

```
class ThreadOne {
    std::thread thread;
public:
    ~ThreadOne();
    //...

};

//...

ThreadOne::ThreadOne() {
    thread = std::thread{RealThread, this};
}

ThreadOne::~ThreadOne() {
    // (potentially) notify thread to finish first
    if(thread.joinable())
        thread.join();
}    

//...

ThreadOne tWrite;
```

Note that I did not start the thread in the member-initializer-list of the constructor in order to avoid the thread accessing other members that have not been initialized yet. (The default constructor of `std::thread` does not start any thread.)

I also wrote a destructor which will wait for the thread to finish and join it. You must always join threads before destroying the `std::thread` object attached to it, otherwise your program will call `std::terminate` and abort.

Finally, I replaced `tWrite` from being a pointer to being a class type directly. There is probably no reason for you to use dynamic allocation there and even if you have a need for it, you should be using

```
auto tWrite = std::make_unique<ThreadOne>();
```

or equivalent, instead, so that you are not going to rely on manually `delete`ing the pointer at the correct place.

Also note that your current `RealThread` function seems to never finish. It must return at some point, probably after receiving a notification from the main thread, otherwise `thread.join()` will wait forever.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and example code!